# what kind of file is public.composite-content (kUTTypeCompositeContent)?

Tags: cocoa, file-type, uti

i'm writing a file importer and want to handle **pdf** types. i see the **com.adobe.pdf** (`kUTTypePDF`) and also `public.composite-content` type.

**Uniform Type Identifiers Reference** docs :

> Base type for mixed content. For example, a PDF file contains both
>   text and special formatting data.

can someone kindly give an example of this type of file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `com.adobe.pdf` identifier inherits from `public.composite-content`. In other words, PDF documents are a specific subset of all documents that conform to `public.composite-content`.

As you can see in the [reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html), there are many types that conform to `public.composite-content`, such as `com.apple.rtfd` (for RTF documents), `com.apple.webarchive` and `public.presentation` for presentation files (Keynote, Powerpoint etc).

The main distinguishing feature of `public.composite-content` files is that they combine different specific types of data in one file, as opposed to types inheriting from `public.data` which are just binary blobs. I personally think the distinction is not exactly clear-cut but there you go.

If you want to handle PDF types, you just need to declare conformance to `com.adobe.pdf`.

Comment: `public.composite-content` shouldn’t be contrasted with `public.data`. `public.composite-content` is part of the “functional hierarchy”, derived from `public.content`, which describes _conceptual_ types; `public.data` is the root of the “physical hierarchy”, which describes _representations_. File (and package) types should conform to types in both hierarchies. For example, PDF conforms to `public.composite-content` and `public.data`, while RTFD conforms to `public.composite-content` and `com.apple.package`.

Comment: @Rob: Can you help me with UTI type for contents in iOS Notes App. What type of UTI they support?